# Install Oh My Zsh on a Vagrant Box as part of the bootstrap process

Tags: vagrant, oh-my-zsh

I'd like to add [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) to my Vagrant bootstrap process, but a straight install isn't working.

via curl:

```
curl -L http://install.ohmyz.sh | sh
```

via wget:

```
wget --no-check-certificate http://install.ohmyz.sh -O - | sh
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
# Added zsh shell.
sudo apt-get install zsh
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh -O - | sh 
sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh vagrant
zsh
```

As an nice addition, so that your terminals don't look too similar on the different boxes

```
# Change the oh my zsh default theme.
sed -i 's/ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"/ZSH_THEME="3den"/g' ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Where in the Vagrantfile do you add this?

Comment: In the bootstrap file. You may need to install git as well.

Comment: can you provide an example vagrantfile?

Comment: ```sudo apt-get install -y zsh```to automatically install (i need this on Debian)

Comment: Maybe in the future the robbyrussel theme will be not the default one anymore, so you can use `sed -i 's/ZSH_THEME=[^ ]*/ZSH_THEME="3den"/g' ~/.zshrc`

Comment: I try this, but the `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh` installed to `root`. Not in user `vagrant`. So I must install they as user-vagrant but under root.
`su -l vagrant -s "/bin/sh" -c "curl -fsSO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh; chmod 755 install.sh; ./install.sh --unattended"; chsh -s /bin/zsh vagrant`
It is a snippet of my bootstrap. And it works.

Answer (score 24):

Here's a complete `Vagrantfile` that installs Oh My Zsh on an Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS box and sets it as the default shell for standard `vagrant` user.

This works with Vagrant 1.7.2. (Your milage may vary with different versions.) It uses the directions from the [Manual Installation](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh#manual-installation) section of the Readme instead of trying to use the automatic scripts.

```rb
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  # Pick a box to use:
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  ############################################################
  # Oh My ZSH Install section

  # Install git and zsh prerequisites 
  config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "apt-get -y install git"
  config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "apt-get -y install zsh"

  # Clone Oh My Zsh from the git repo
  config.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false,
    inline: "git clone git://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git ~/.oh-my-zsh"

  # Copy in the default .zshrc config file
  config.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false,
    inline: "cp ~/.oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template ~/.zshrc"

  # Change the vagrant user's shell to use zsh
  config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "chsh -s /bin/zsh vagrant"

  ############################################################


end
```

As a bonus, you can do a one time copy of your host machine's `.zshrc` file to the vagrant box with:

```rb
config.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.zshrc", destination: ".zshrc"
```

(Keep in mind, You may have to figure things that don't work initially because of differences between the host machine and the vagrant box's setups.)

Comment: I done `vagrant reload` and I can't use zsh commands like `..`

Comment: I get the zsh installing if I do `vagrant destroy` but then I get error: `==> default: fatal: destination path '/home/vagrant/.oh-my-zsh' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

Comment: Try running `vagrant reload --provision`, if the box is currently running. Otherwise, `vagrant up --provision` if it is not running. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I came here because had a same issue. After seeing some answer and trying it, mostly the `zsh` & `oh-my-zsh` got installed as `root`. The `root` will set his `$SHELL` with `zsh`. What I want is they are installed as user `vagrant`. The bootstrap was done by root when provisioning. So the logic is try to run install `zsh` & `oh-my-zsh` as user. Here is what I did after trying many times until I got what I wanted :

```rb
## In Vagrantfile try to call bootstrap.sh
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap.sh"
```

```sh
## This is the bootstrap.sh
aptInstl() {
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -qq -y $1 > /dev/null
}
install_zsh() {
  aptInstl "zsh"
  su -l vagrant -s "/bin/sh" \
    -c "curl -fsSO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh; chmod 755 install.sh; ./install.sh --unattended"
  chsh -s /bin/zsh vagrant
}
install_miscellaneous() {
  apt-get update > /dev/null
  apt-get upgrade > /dev/null
  for i in curl git; do
    aptInstl "$i"
  done
}
main() {
  install_miscellaneous
  install_zsh
}
main
```

And It works perfectly :)
When you are done try to `vagrant ssh` it will automatically logged you in with `zsh` shell and `oh-my-zsh`. [Here](https://github.com/adibdz/Miscellaneous-Script/tree/main/Vagrantfile) is the complete file.